# Can I build update query with variable fields without using plain SQL?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, slick

Can I build update query with variable number of fields without using plain SQL ?

For example update of single column is simple - I just yield it to create narrow query.

```
Query(RolesTable).filter((role: RolesTable.type) => role.id === role_id).map((role: RolesTable.type) => role.name).update(name)
```

But what if `Role` has 5 fields and I want to allow API client to send me fields he wants to update ? How would I construct such query ?

Answer (score 3):

The key here is to use the `~` operator when yielding the selected columns.  Using the example model from the documentation:

```
case class User(id: Option[Int], first: String, last: String)
object UsersTable extends Table[User]("users") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def first = column[String]("first")
  def last = column[String]("last")
  def * = id.? ~ first ~ last <> (User, User.unapply _)
}
```

A select based on your example would look like this:

```
val cols = Query(UsersTable).filter((user: UsersTable.type) => user.id === userId).map((user: UsersTable.type) => user.first ~ user.last)
```

And then the `update` call would be:

```
cols.update((newFirst,newLast))
```

Also, if you wanted, you could re-write your select as a for comprehension as it shortens it up a bit:

```
val cols = for(user <- UsersTable if (user.id === userId)) yield user.first ~ user.last
cols.update((newFirst,newLast))
```

Comment: But what if fields that should be concatenated will be known only in runtime ?

Comment: I'm guessing that you can't do this with my approach from above.  Combining columns together creates a projection that is statically typed to the columns that are being combined together.  Then, the `update` signature is based on the types for this projection and can all be checked for correctness at compile time.  I'm just not sure how this would work with a dynamic column list and then a dynamic set of values to use for the call to `update`.