# How do you use StaticQuery.update in Slick with parameters?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, slick

Could you please demonstrate how to use Slick's [StaticQuery.update](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1-RC1/api/#scala.slick.jdbc.StaticQuery) **with** parameters ? [Documentation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1-RC1/sql.html) shows only parameterless call. I didn't find example in unit-tests either.

Comment: I can give you an example using plain sql if you want.  Our whole data layer is built on slick plain sql, so I have plenty examples of updates.  Just not sure you wanted to see it as the plan sql flavor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simple example, showing an update with two input params.  Note that this code assumes that an implicit `Session` is in scope:

```
import scala.slick.jdbc.{StaticQuery => Q}
val updateEmailSql = Q.update[(String,Long)]("update User set email = ? where id = ?")
val rowsUpdated = updateEmailSql(("foo@test.com", 1L)).first()
```

The `rowsUpdated` val here will be an `Int` representing the number of rows that were affected by this update statement.

Comment: Thank you!! Could you please also suggest how to solve this problem with Slick ? http://stackoverflow.com/q/16756086/226895

Comment: What about a case with using the same parameter multiple times in the query?